# How to fill a ListBox with a background worker in .Net2.0?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

In my application a ListBox is filled after a user puts more than two characters into a textBox.

If there is a lot to fill into the ListBox, the user has to wait until the ListBox is completely filled before is able to continue his input.

Now I need a solution to fill the ListBox without blocking the UI, so I would like to use a background worker to solve this.

---- Original Version -----

In my application I fill a ListBox when the user puts in more then two characters into a textBox.
The ListBox fills with results and after this, the user is able to put in more characters.

My problem is the following behaviour: The user is only able to put in the next char *after* the whole ListBox is filled with all entries. If there are a lot of results the user has to wait until he is able to continue.

I would like to have the following behaviour: If the user puts in a char, the filling of the ListBox should stop and build the list for the new input.

I thought about sth. like:

```
[PSEUDO-CODE]
loop over results {
    if (UserInput) {    // <-- GetKeyState()?
        break
    }

    AddOneItemToListBox
}
[/PSEUDO-CODE]
```

I thought about sth. like GetKeyState() but I think there should be a more elegant way (perhaps a control or another technology I don't know about ATM).

P.S.: Currently I'm looking for a solution with .Net2.0, but if there is a technology inside a later version of .Net I would also be glad for a short hint (just for my information).

Comment: The delay is because you're doing the updating on the UI thread. The user is blocked from doing anything with your application until your loop finishes running. Oliver's suggestion to use a `BackgroundWorker` instead is the simplest and probably best workaround. I'm not really sure why you were thinking of using `GetKeyState`; what would that do for you?

Comment: @Cody: If there is a user input I would like to leave the loop which is filling the ListBox.

Comment: I didn't suggest eliminating the loop. I suggested (see Oliver's answer for details) moving it to a `BackgroundWorker` thread. That way, the loop will run in the *background*, instead of blocking the user from entering characters. If this *isn't* what you're looking for, please edit your question to make your goal more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fill the the ListBox within a `BackgroundWorker` (don't forget to call the `Add()` method with `BeginInvoke()`). In this case the user can already interact with the GUI while the box will be filled.

If the user adds something to the box on himself you can stop the autofill by calling `worker.CancelAsnyc()`.

#### Update (compatible with VS 2005)

Unfortunately i don't have VS2005 to try it out, but i removed all the fancy lambda, etc. stuff.

Just a simple sample for starting:

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    BackgroundWorker _Worker;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _Worker = new BackgroundWorker();

        _Worker.DoWork += OnWorkerDoWork;
        _Worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        this.Shown += OnFormMainShown;
    }

    void OnFormMainShown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void OnWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (_Worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                return;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            listBox1.Invoke((Action<int>)AddItem, i);
        }
    }

    private void AddItem(int i)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(i);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Worker.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a sample for .net2.0? listBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => listBox1.Items.Add(i)));
 throws an error: sth. like "1-Typeargument necessary" (using german VS so don't know the correct message).

Comment: @Inno: No, that won't work on .NET 2.0. He's using lambda expressions, which I don't believe were introduced until .NET 3.0 or 3.5. There is a great example of `BackgroundWorker` posted on MSDN, though. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx).

Comment: @Cody - lambda expressions work great in .Net 2.0, as long as you're using >3.5 compiler.

Comment: @Inno - make sure you're referencing System.Action, and not one of its generic overloads

Comment: @David: Yeah, I'm perfectly aware of that. I assumed that since @Inno said the code didn't work that he *wasn't* using the .NET 3.5 compiler. You have to have the requisite version of Visual Studio to have that compiler.

Comment: So I have to compile my assembly with .Net3.5 to get lambda expressions but it would still run on a .net2.0-only machine?

Comment: @Inno: In VS2008 you can select as TargetFramework .Net 2.0. So your application will run on the .Net 2.0 framework. The lambdas, anonymous methods and extension methods are just syntactic sugar which will be matched to the corresponding functions by the compiler independent of the framework version you are using.

Comment: @Inno: But to make it even simpler, i just changed the code to be understandable even by the VS2005 compiler.

Comment: @Oliver: Hm, then it should work out of the box, I'm using VS2010. Target framework is 2.0. I converted the project from VS2005 to VS2010, is this the problem?

Comment: @Oliver: Just saw your update. Works fine! Thank you very much. Do I have to mention sth. when running this on a terminal server?

Comment: @Inno: No problem, by upgrading vom VS2005 to VS2010 for C# projects (as far as i know). You can get into trouble by upgrading from VS2001 or VS2003 to any higher for .net languages or by trying to upgrade C++/CLI projects into any VS version.

Comment: @Inno: Nothing to mention, cause it simply runs within its own session, like it would do on any client machine.